# How to pass req values into Sequelize findAll

Tags: reactjs, express, sequelize.js, react-hooks

How to pass `email` and `password` values from req using `Sequelize findAll()` to query the email and password from the database. Below is my select query that I need to perform;

`select email, password from user where email="some_email@testmail.com";`

While sending the request, I am getting below error in the n/w tab response:

{"message":"WHERE parameter \"email\" has invalid \"undefined\" value"}

`server.js`

```
app.get('/service/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const loginData = await UserModel.findAll({ where: { email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password} });
    console.log(loginData);
    res.status(200).json({ loginData });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
  }
});
```

`login.js`

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/login');
        setLoginData(res.data.loginData); 
        console.log("Get data from database:"+loginData.password);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `get` method to `post`

In Node :

```
app.post('/service/login'
// then you will be able to access `req.body`
```

In React :

```
// you were not even passing the email and password
await Axios.post('http://localhost:8000/service/login',{ email , password });
```

Comment: May I ask why we need to add `post` instead of get, as we are planning to get data from database. Sorry if I my question too blunt or doesn't make any sense..

Comment: Yes no problem, but to get data you need to post some data right? To login you need to pass some info and that should not be passed as query param, and as a result of posting data you will get some data, whenever you are passing some data something related to form submit you can use post, but you can use get when searching or filtering or listing some data.

Comment: Do you know `findAll({ where: { email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password} });` is correct ?

Comment: Sorry Get data from database:undefined, ` console.log("Get data from database:"+loginData.password);`

Comment: Yes looks good to me , first check are you even getting data inside node? , if yes whats `loginData` if that is correct then you can check whats the output of `res.data.loginData` in react? this is how you can debug

Comment: Inside Node `res.status(200).json({ loginData });` this is printing as blank when i check in n/w tab

Comment: Made changes as following const userEmail = req.body.email;
    const userPassword = req.body.password;
    const loginData = await UserModel.findAll({ where: { email: userEmail, password: userPassword} });` Restarted the server and its working now...